# Medicine problem

Tags: logical-deduction

Laura has to take 2 different kind of medicines (medicine 1, medicine 2). both look exactly the same (same weight, color, shape, size, etc…; i.e identical).

If she takes more than 1 medicine of the same kind per day, she will die. Furthermore, if she doesn’t take medicine 1 and 2 every day,  she will also die.

Laura is on a limited budget, and since the medicines are extremely expensive, she can’t throw any of them away.

One day, she got distracted and by mistake put 2 medicines on the table. Since both medicine types look identical, she’s not sure which medicine is which.

> Question: How can she manage to take the medicines without any further
>   dire consequences and yet save the extra medicine?

Comment: "...and by mistake put 1 medicines on the table". Do you mean she put a single pill on the table?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I meant  ***...and by mistake put 2 medicines on the table***

Question edited.

Comment: how about medicine taste ?

Comment: **Laura is on a limited budget**

Comment: whether she kept two medicines from two different box or same box.....does this recalled by her ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One day, she got distracted and by mistake put 2 medicines on the table. Since both medicine types look identical, she’s not sure which medicine is which.

As I understood she should take 1 of each every day and she has put 2 of each on the table. Then the answer is:

> Cut each of the 4 pills in 2 and eat a half of each pill. Eat the other halves tomorrow.
>  Like that she will consume $2*(1*0.5)$ of medicine 1 and $2*(1*0.5)$ of medicine 2, so exactly 1 of each.